# So i have my benq rl2455hm ,the Hue and Saturation Settings are greyed out

Tags: display, hdmi, gaming, ps4

So i have my benq rl2455hm hooked up via HDMI to my PS4 and on every source,the Hue and Saturation Settings are grayed out. Is there any way to make these settings accessible?

Answer (score 1):

It only works on PC over HDMI You need to go into Nvidia control panel and switch the color output from RGB to YCbCr in order for Hue and Saturation to appear. PS4 & XboxOne don't have that option to switch from RGB to YCbCr no more they removed it back in 2015 so nothing you can do it only let's you switch between RGB Full or Limited. Your monitors fine.

https://www.benq.eu/en-eu/support/downloads-faq/faq/product/explanation/monitor-faq-k-00021.html